# How can I use my service name in the secret instead of the ip address?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, openshift, redhat

I'm doing a wordpress deployment, but since the ip address of the service is not always static, I should use the name of the service in my secret which currently looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: wordpress-secret
stringData:
  WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "wordpress"
  WORDPRESS_DB_USERNAME: "admin"
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "password"
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "1.1.1.1"
  WORDPRESS_DB_PORT: "3306"
```

So how can I make everything dynamic? because obviously the ip address is not always static of the service

Answer (score 1):

Services in the same namespace can be reached using the name of the service. If the service is called `my-db`, you simply write `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: “my-db”`.